# Crontab : does not manage dependencies in Python

Tags: python, import, cron

I want to run a Python script every hour. I found that one solution is add it in a crontab (I am using Mac OS X).

I added the command `python myscript.py` in the crontab by doing:

```
crontab -e
0 * * * * python myscript.py
```

The script seems to be launched as wanted but the script can not find the modules I import (ImportError in python).

Note that when I write `python myscript.py` directly in the terminal, it is well executed.

The mail I receive:

[image]

Do you have any suggestions to fix that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Where did you install the requests modules? Was this globally or in a virtualenv?

Comment: Thank you for your answer,

I installed the modules using the pip command, so I guess it is globally.
We can find the packages in a folder called /Users/user/anaconda2/pkgs.

When I write the command directly in the terminal, there is no Import error.

Comment: EDIT: problem solved thanks to Tomaz's answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are missing is the path to python source... , example looks like  `*/10 * * * * /usr/local/bin/python script.py` for mac OS, if you installed modules globally, if you used virtualenv you have to specify path to virtualenv source.

Hope this helps